# How to loop through a dataset break and then restart the loop from that point where it broke?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataset that contains a series of values which are, negative, positive and zeros. I would like to loop through the dataset and store all the periods that have negative and zero clusters. Once positive values are encountered these need to be skipped and a new list started once negative values are encountered again and so on. Also, each cluster should be stored in a separate list. I have the following code:

```
cloud = []
for i in range(0,ndata[:,1].shape[0]):
    if ndata[:,1][i] <= 0:
        print(ndata[:,0][i])
        cloud.append(ndata[:,0][i])
    else:
        break
```

but I am not sure how to get the loop to restart from the point where it stopped and move to the next batch of negative values.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,ndata[:,1].shape[0]):
    if ndata[:,1][i] <= 0:
        print(ndata[:,0][i])
        cloud.append(ndata[:,0][i])
    else:
        j = i
        break
```

Later...

```
for i in range (j, nadata[:,1].shape[0]):
```

Comment: What if there is more than one cluster?

Comment: thanks for your help @MahmoodDarwish. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
clouds = []
    record = False
    cloud = []
    for i in range(0, data[:, 1].shape[0]):
        if data[:, 1][i] < 0:
            record = True
        else:
            record = False

        if record == True:
            cloud.append(data[:, 0][i])
            continue

        if record == False and len(cloud) > 0:
            clouds.append(cloud)
            cloud = []
```